# telegram bot: Как отправлять сообщения в чат без /start?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Создал бота, используя фреймворк [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).

Пишем в чат `/start`, бот отвечает "Hi!", всё работает

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, RegexHandler
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
        
TOKEN = '123'
REQUEST_KWARGS={
    # "USERNAME:PASSWORD@" is optional, if you need authentication:
    'proxy_url': 'http://123:123@123:65233/',
}
                
def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hi!")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)   
    updater.start_polling()
```

Но как отправить сообщение в чат без `/start`?
Как, допустим, каждые 5 секунд отправлять произвольное сообщение?

Comment: Как минимум, пользователь должен начать работу с вашим ботом, чтобы можно было отправлять ему сообщения с периодичностью раз в 5 минут.

Comment: то есть в моем случае, в функции start сделать бесконечный цикл, который будет что-то делать?  или можно как-то уже, имея первый коннект, отправлять сообщения из других функций или методов итд.

Answer (score -1):

Сам решил, может кому пригодится. По сути передаем updater и context в поток и выполняем нужные вычисления и шлем результат

**main.py**

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, RegexHandler
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from thread_class import *

TOKEN = 'xxx'
REQUEST_KWARGS={'proxy_url': 'http://xxx',}

def start(update, context):
        #выполняем то что связано с запуском 
        thread.bot_updater(update, context)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # запускаем поток
    thread = ThreadData()
    thread.start()

    # запускаем бота телеграм
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)    
    updater.start_polling()
```

**class_thread.py**

```
    #поток связанный с ботом
    import threading
    from time import sleep

    class ThreadData(threading.Thread):
        """StartTrade"""
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.go = False
            self.update = None
            self.context = None        

        def run(self):
            self.start_thread()

        def start_thread(self):
            while True:
                if self.go:
                   text = 'ЭТО СООБЩЕНИЕ КАЖДЫЕ 5 СЕКУНД'
                   self.context.bot.send_message(chat_id=self.update.effective_chat.id, text=text)               
                   sleep(5)

        def bot_updater(self, update, context):
            self.update = update
            self.context = context
            self.go = True
```